# Get latest transaction details from loanhist

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, sqlsrv

I have a loan history table which contain all the loans a customer borrowed and repayed. There are two status(on the same row) that indicate loan borrow and loan repay: LD = loan disburse while LP = Loan Paid.

My problem is this, I am trying to find:

1. outstanding balance(sum(principal+interest) in LD - sum(principal+interest) in LP)
2. Installment amount(sum(principal+interest)) in LD
3. SUM of all LD i.e principal + interest as loan amount
4. Last repayment date i.e in LP
5. Amount paid(principal+interest) in LP

Table structure

[image]

This is my solution so far:

**for LP**

```
$amtdues = "select h.ac_no, loan_amt, MAX(trx_date) AS Last_Pay, MAX(principal+interest) as Last_Paid,  disb_date, exp_date,  principal+interest as loan_interest, MAX(principal-interest) as outstanding_balance, trx_date as payment_date from loanhist h, loans l where h.ac_no = '$id' and l.ac_no = '$id' and trx_type = 'LP' group by trx_date, loan_amt, disb_date, exp_date, h.ac_no, interest, principal, trx_date ";

$amts = sqlsrv_query($conn, $amtdues);

$lp = sqlsrv_fetch_array($amts, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

**For LD**

```
$amtdues2 = "select h.ac_no, loan_amt, MAX(trx_date) AS Last_Pay, disb_date, exp_date,  principal+interest as loan_interest, MAX(interest+principal) as outstanding_balance, MAX(interest+principal) as installment, trx_date as payment_date from loanhist h, loans l where h.ac_no = '$id' and l.ac_no = '$id' and trx_type = 'LD' group by trx_date, loan_amt, disb_date, exp_date, h.ac_no, interest, principal, trx_date ";

$amts2 = sqlsrv_query($conn, $amtdues2);
$ld = sqlsrv_fetch_array($amts2, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

My output in html

```
<td><?php echo parseCurrency(abs($lmts['loan_limit']));?></td>
 <td><?php echo parseCurrency(abs($ld['loan_interest']));?></td>
 <td><?php echo parseCurrency(abs($ld['outstanding_balance'] - $lp['outstanding_balance']));?> </td>
 <td><?php echo parseCurrency(abs($ld['installment']));?></td>
```

After I tried these queries, I got incorrect values. Could someone pls help a sister out?

Comment: You've asked for 5 queries, which is too broad IMO.  Can you narrow it down to asking for just 2, or better yet, 1, query?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, Just need someone to point me to the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: If you could share your table structure and some sample data it would make it much easier to answer your question.

Comment: @Nick, table added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the table information for `loanhist` and making some assumption about what's in `loans` (and that there is a 1:many relationship from `loans` to `loanhist`), I think this query will start you off in the right direction.

```
SELECT l.ac_no, 
       l.loan_amt,
       l.disb_date, 
       l.exp_date,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN trx_type='LD' THEN h.principal+h.interest ELSE 0 END) -
         SUM(CASE WHEN trx_type='LP' THEN h.principal+h.interest ELSE 0 END) AS outstanding_balance,
       MAX(CASE WHEN trx_type='LD' THEN h.principal+h.interest ELSE 0 END) AS instalment_amount,  
       SUM(CASE WHEN trx_type='LD' THEN h.principal+h.interest ELSE 0 END) AS loan_amount,
       MAX(CASE WHEN trx_type='LP' THEN trx_date ELSE NULL END) AS last_payment_date,
       SUM(CASE WHEN trx_type='LP' THEN h.principal+h.interest ELSE 0 END) AS amount_paid
FROM loans l
JOIN loanhist h
ON h.ac_no = l.ac_no
WHERE l.ac_no = '$id'
GROUP BY l.ac_no, l.loan_amt, l.disb_date, l.exp_date
```

Comment: thanks for your help. The code didn't run - it returns no values and when tested in sql server it says "Incorrect syntax near CASE, expecting select or ;('"

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I was missing a comma after `outstanding_balance`

Comment: Hello @Nick, I so much appreciate your help. I'll let u know how it goes after test running it on the main server. I had to group l.ac_no, 
     l.loan_amt,  l.disb_date,  l.exp_date hope it still gives the right figures that way? Cause it gave error when I only group by l.ac_no.

Comment: It should be fine to group by those variables as well. I should have included that in the original query, I have edited my answer.